# Throwing an exception while static initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

The terminate() article on cppreference.com states that if a static or thead-local object throws an exception during construction, then terminate() will be called. I wanted to verify this using a static object that is a local variable, but I was able to catch the exception from the constructor itself. This is more in line with my expectations, because the initialization takes place once within the first thread that goes through the initialization. With the destructor, I can understand that terminate() is then called, because it only starts after main(). What does the standard say in this case?

In the following program I can catch the exception using MSVC, clang++ and g++.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct S
    {
        S() { throw invalid_argument( "hello world" ); };
    };
    try
    {
        static S s;
    }
    catch( exception const &exc )
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the link to the cppref article for context.

Comment: The standard correctly specifies "non-local" where cppreference may omit it https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/except.terminate#1.5.

Comment: Interestingly, [the draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.terminate#1.5) says "non-block" instead. I wonder what's the difference.

Comment: In case it's not clear, the reason for calling `terminate()` is that there's no place to write a `try ... catch` around construction of a non-local static object.

Comment: Oversight in the cppreference `terminate` page.  Mistakes were made; lessons were learned.

Answer (score 4):

> What does the standard say in this case?

This seems to be an editing mistake in the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) article as the [except.terminate#1.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/except.terminate#1.5) specifies the behavior you're observing:

> In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less subtle error handling techniques. [ **Note**: These situations are:
>
> - when initialization of a **non-local variable** with static or thread storage duration** ([basic.start.init]) **exits via an exception**, or

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasis on the "non-local" part of the quoted reference which is missing in the cppreference article.

---

Additionally, there is [basic.start.dynamic](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.dynamic#8):

> If the initialization of a **non-block variable** with static or thread storage duration exits via an exception, the function std​::​terminate is called ([except.terminate]).

Comment: I'm amazed by the "In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less subtle error handling techniques." being part of the normative bit. This is peak Standard Humour.

Comment: @YSC Sounds like Stroustrup.